# JQuery, Canvas, Updating a variable

Tags: jquery, canvas

I am trying to learn some JQuery, mainly for fun, but also for seriouz.
This is a tiny program, it displays the width of the window upon load of the document.

```
function window_width(window_w){

    var window_w = ($(window).width());
    var canvas = document.getElementById("width_w");
    if (canvas.getContext) {   
    var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
    ctx.strokeText(window_w, 0, 10);
    ctx.stroke();
}
}
```

What I want it to do further is to keep updating the display of this variable as someone would re-size the window. I am not sure how to do this, do I need to write another function or is there a method for it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can bind a function to the [resize](http://api.jquery.com/resize/) event with jQuery:

```
$(window).resize(function() {
  // You can put the code from your window_width function here.
});
```

Comment: Thank you! Tried this logic but with a faulty syntax before coming here. Works now! Great!